Unknown Magic Byte - Kafka Json
I've been strugglin with some problemas working along with kafka streams and how my consumer expected the data. My pipeline works like next:

I configured a source connector  of couchbase that add the next message to a topic:

{
    "name": "couchbase-source-connector",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "com.couchbase.connect.kafka.CouchbaseSourceConnector",
        "couchbase.persistence.polling.interval": "100ms",
        "tasks.max": "2",
        "couchbase.seed.nodes": "couchbasedb",
        "couchbase.collections": "art-school-scope.student-record-collection",
        "couchbase.bucket": "student-bucket",
        "couchbase.username": "username",
        "couchbase.password": "password",
        "couchbase.stream.from": "NOW",
        "couchbase.source.handler": "com.couchbase.connect.kafka.handler.source.RawJsonSourceHandler",
        "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
        "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.ByteArrayConverter",
        "couchbase.topic": "topicstream"
    }
}

{"xyz": "Test from couchbase"}

My message ever adds succesfully to the topic. Then I need to send to a database.

I tried to implement with kafka streams.

 void startStreaming() {
            Properties props = new Properties();
            props.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "kafkastreamtopic");
            props.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
            props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass());
            props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass());
            props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_TIMESTAMP_EXTRACTOR_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.FailOnInvalidTimestamp");

            StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();
            builder.<String, String>stream("topicstream")
                    .mapValues(value -> {
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(value);
                            // Extract the "xyz" field
                            String xyz = jsonObject.optString("xyz", null);
                            // Create a new JSON object with the correct format
                            JSONObject transformedObject = new JSONObject();
                            transformedObject.put("xyz", xyz);
                            return transformedObject.toString();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            // Log and handle the error appropriately
                            logger.error("Error transforming value: {}", value, e);
                            return value; // Return the original value in case of error
                        }
                    })
                    .to("jdbcsinktopic2", Produced.valueSerde(Serdes.String()));

            KafkaStreams kafkaStreams = new KafkaStreams(builder.build(), props);
            kafkaStreams.setStateListener((newState, oldState) -> {
                logger.info("State changed from " + oldState + " to " + newState);
            });

            kafkaStreams.start();

            Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(kafkaStreams::close));

The code above writes succesfully the message onto jdbcsinktopic2 and I can see like this:
{"xyz":"Test from couchbase"}


Also I added a schema to schema registry and my sink configuration

kafka-json-schema-console-producer --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --property schema.registry.url=http://localhost:8081 --topic jdbcsinktopic2 --property value.schema='{"type":"object", "properties":{"xyz":{"type":"string"}}}'

when I tested it by adding the message when I created the schema the data got inserted on my database without any problem.
{
    "name": "mysql-sink-2",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
        "tasks.max": "1",
        "topics": "jdbcsinktopic2",
        "connection.url": "jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306/inventory",
        "connection.username": "debeziumexample",
        "connection.password": "example",
        "auto.create": "true",
        "insert.mode": "insert",
        "pk.mode": "none",
        "value.converter.schemas.enable": "true",
        "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.json.JsonSchemaConverter",
        "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://schema-registry:8081",
        "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
        "key.converter.schemas.enable": "true",
        "errors.tolerance": "all",
        "errors.log.enable": true,
        "errors.log.include.messages": true
    }
}

The problem comes when I transform the data and how my consumer expected it. I'm quite new at this topic. How can I manage this data to send it transformed with my kafka stream application to my database through my jdbcsink?
Any advice, correction or help would be amazing.
Regards,
Rigo

Can you share the source connector configuration? It's not clear why you need kafka streams

@OneCricketeer I edited the post. This message are on RawJsonSourceHandler class that provide couchbase connector and the value converter is on org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.ByteArrayConverter.

I resumed the project after some time and finally I succeeded in solving my problem.
First, I need to configure my Couchbase Source Connector. There were no changes required (wich you can see above).
I started to use schema Registry and ksqldb. My messages wich came from Couchbase was a simple json objects as follows. (Schema less json)
{"xyz":"This is a value"}

Then by using ksqldb I executed the following statements:
CREATE STREAM smjson (xyz VARCHAR) WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='topicstream', VALUE_FORMAT='JSON');

SELECT * FROM smjson EMIT CHANGES;

CREATE STREAM SOME_JSON_AS_AVRO WITH (VALUE_FORMAT='AVRO') AS SELECT * FROM smjson;

It's necessary add to your ksqldb server the configuration to connect with schema registry and executed the above statements, on "http://schema-registry:8081/schemas". After that you will see the schemas autogenerated.
After this, you can configure your JdbcSinkConnector as the next example:
{
    "name": "mysql-sink",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
        "tasks.max": "1",
        "topics": "SOME_JSON_AS_AVRO",
        "connection.url": "jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306/inventory",
        "connection.username": "*",
        "connection.password": "*",
        "auto.create": "true",
        "auto.evolve": "true",
        "insert.mode": "insert",
        "pk.mode": "none",
        "key.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
        "key.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://schema-registry:8081",
        "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
        "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://schema-registry:8081",
        "quote.identifiers": "true",
        "errors.tolerance": "all",
        "errors.log.enable": true,
        "errors.log.include.messages": true
    }
}

After this, your implementation to move data from Couchbase to any Relational Database should be working.
Also, I highly recommend to follow those tutorials Kafka Connect in Action: JDBC Sink from Robin Moffatt channel

David answered you question on Couchbase forums:
https://www.couchbase.com/forums/t/couchbase-kafka-jdbcsink/38937
Hi @Rigoberto12 ,
I suspect the problem may be that the Couchbase connector is not emitting documents in a schema-aware format.
From your config, it looks like you’re using com.couchbase.connect.kafka.handler.source.RawJsonSourceHandler, which does not emit schemas.
Out of the box, the connector supports a single schema, the one used by DefaultSchemaSourceHandler. That schema is documented here: Quickstart | Couchbase Docs 1
Frankly, that schema is not very useful, because it says nothing about the structure of your documents; instead, it applies a schema to the document metadata, and treats the document content as a blob.
In order to use a real custom schema, you would need to write your own custom SourceHandler that builds the source record in a schema-aware manner. Unfortunately, we don’t have a great example of how to do this. My impression is that your custom SourceHandler would first need to parse the document JSON to ensure it conforms to your schema, then add each document field to the Kafka Connect SourceRecord one by one, specifying the appropriate schema information for each field. It’s a real pain in the neck, and in many cases not worth the trouble, in my opinion.
If you want to try it anyway, there’s a sample project you can use to get started here: kafka-connect-couchbase/examples/custom-extensions at master · couchbase/kafka-connect-couchbase · GitHub
Another alternative might be to let the Couchbase connector publish the raw document JSON, and then use a different component to transform the record by applying the schema. Maybe a Single Message Transform (SMT) could do this, or a solution based of Kafka Streams. (I’m just guessing about this, though.)
Thanks,
David

You've produced a message with a String Serde, not the Jsonschema serde from Confluent. Therefore, there's no "magic byte" in the record.
https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/blob/master/json-schema-serde/src/main/java/io/confluent/kafka/streams/serdes/json/KafkaJsonSchemaSerde.java
When you produce with the correct serde, it'll automatically register the schema in the Registry
Also, "schemas.enable": "true" is only applicable to JsonConverter class builtin to Kafka, not JsonschemaConverter from Confluent, as that one always enforces a schema

Thanks so much for shared, I will check it out.
